# Handling a complex line integral (Homework)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Evaluate $$\oint_{\gamma} \frac{\bar{z}}{8+z}dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the rectangle whose endpoints are $\pm 3 \pm i$, oriented counterclockwise.

This one has been a relatively frustrating struggle for me. My attempts have centered around breaking the rectangle into the four obvious pieces, e.g. $\gamma_1 = (3-6t)+i$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$ etc. Then, I've tried direct substitution, e.g.: $$\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{\bar{z}}{8+z}dz=\int_0^1 \frac {(3-6t)-i}{11-6t+i}(-6)\,dt$$

and I've also tried multiplying the numerator and denominator by $8+\bar{z}$ and then converting to real and imaginary components. Either way, I'm stuck on horrific computations and I keep wondering if there is not some simpler hint I am failing to see.

Comment: Possible hint: On the individual line segments, replace $\bar z$ with an expression involving $z$. Then use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: That's one of the ways I wanted to approach it, but I have a hard time manipulating $\frac{\bar{z}}{8+z}$ into a holomorphic function on the pieces, which would be what is needed to use the FTC - no?

Comment: Yes, that's why I said to rewrite $\bar z$. If you're on the line $\Im z=1$, what is $\bar z$?

Comment: $\Im \bar{z}=-1$ with $\Re \bar{z}=\Re z.$ However, would this not reorient the denominator as well? EDIT: If I multiply the numerator and denominator by $8+\bar{z}$ this should not matter. I will try your suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: What techniques do you know for handling complex integrals?

Comment: We are supposed to use elementary means, i.e. the definition of a complex line integral for a continuous function f(z) on an open set $U$ containing the $C^1$ curve $\gamma: [a,b]->U$, and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for $f(z)$ holomorphic on an open set. We may also cheat a little and use Cauchy's Integral Formula and Theorem. See Greene and Krantz, Function Theory of One Complex Variable, chapter 2 question 4d for a similar example (the same problem oriented clockwise instead of CCW).

Comment: You still aren't where I was trying to point you, Darrin. We have $z-\bar z =2i$, so $\bar z = z-2i$. Now substitute and simplify the integrand.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I think I catch your drift now. To check, the application of your hint across $\gamma_1$ as given above yields an expression involving complex logs after application of FTC. I will then calculate the component along bottom horizontal side of $\gamma$ the same way (using $\bar{z}=z+2i$). For the vertical sides, I should replace $\bar{z}$ with $z$ and multiply those results by $-1$. The integral result will be the sum of those four components.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing I see is that your integral is of the form

$$\int \frac{\text{polynomial in }t}{\text{other polynomial in }t}\mathrm{d}t$$

In other words, it's the integral of a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function). These are in some sense the "simplest" functions to integrate; not in the sense that the integral will always be *easy* to figure out, but there is a more or less straightforward procedure for doing them using [partial fraction decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fractions_in_integration#Application_to_symbolic_integration), so you're at least guaranteed to get an answer, which is more than you can say for an arbitrary function.

In this particular case, both the polynomials are linear, so it's a particularly easy case. You could try the partial fraction method, or you could check your textbook/notes or search online for information on how to do this type of integral specifically. Remember, it's basically this:

$$\int\frac{x - a}{x - b}\mathrm{d}x$$

That doesn't look so bad, does it?

Comment: David, yes, I suppose I could suffer accusations of being lazy here! Mucking through it gets a few log and arctan results. Perhaps that is the correct way to go, but I am checking if there is an obvious "break it up this way and you can use Cauchy" type of approach that I need to be seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make the computations easier

I would say first make the representation a little bit easier by $$I=\oint \frac{\bar{z}+z-z}{8+z} \, dz =\oint \frac{2\text{Re}(z)}{8+z} \, dz-\oint \frac{z}{z+8} \, dz   $$
Since the branch point is away from the contour we can find an analytic branch of the logarithm where the branch cut is chosen away from the contour.

Comment: There is no way to handle the first of your integrals on the right-hand side.

Comment: @TedShifrin , you mean the integral with $Re(z)$ ?